# Merge two audio/webm blobs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

my application lets people record voice messages. I do that with react-mic.

The output files are web and very reasonable in size. I upload them to cloudinary.

I have an audio merger called [crunker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crunker) - it's an npm package.

I'm merging two previously recorded audio webms into one file and upload them.

The only problem is - Crunker takes to small files and merges them into a huge wav file.

Ten times the needed size. Can anyone point me in a direction where i could write this myself and put out something that is WebM as well?

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (crunkerRef.current) {
      let audio = new Crunker();
      audio
        .fetchAudio(oldAudioFileUrl, newAudioFileUrl)
        .then(buffers => audio.mergeAudio(buffers))
        .then(merged => audio.export(merged, 'audio/webm'))
        .then(output => {
          const file_reader = new FileReader();
          const dateOfRecording = Date.now();
          file_reader.readAsDataURL(output.blob);
          file_reader.onloadend = async function() {
            const base64_string = file_reader.result;
            await uploadAudio(base64_string, author, chatId, dateOfRecording);
            return base64_string;
          };
          setConsolidatedAudioFileName(`${chatId}-${dateOfRecording}-${author}.webm`);
          setTimeout(() => setConsolidationDone(true), 1500);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          throw new Error(error);
        });
    }
  }, [chatId, author, newAudioFileUrl, oldAudioFileUrl]);
```

This is what I'm doing. 
I'm aiming to write an own function that is not turning out a huge file and stays in WebM.

Comment: Crunker only outputs WAV data (see https://github.com/jackedgson/crunker/blob/master/src/crunker.js#L108-L127). You'll have to encode to whatever format yourself.

Comment: yes i know. that's why i'm here.

Comment: Well, you should be able to feed the (floating-point audio data) output from `mergeAudio` into the audio encoder of your choosing. I'm not sure if there's a browser-native way to encode buffers (back) to Opus, but there's NPM.